# Euler method for chemical system

Tags: euler-lagrange-equation, python, chemistry

I have a simple chemical system $A\rightarrow B$ with $k_1$ and $A_1\rightarrow B$ with $k_2$. I can easily solve it with different packages but I wanted to learn the Euler way. I am solving it in Python. I can describe $A$ and $A_1$ but with $B$ I have some difficulties, hope you guys could help. 
so the equations goes like this:

```
da_dt = -k1* ca
da1_dt = -k2 *ca1
db_dt = (k1 * ca) + (k2 * ca1)
```

In python euler I wrote it like that :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt
Nt = 1000
time = 10
delt = time/Nt
ca0_0 = 1
ca1_0 = 0.5
k1 = 1
k2 = 1
tt = np.linspace(0,time,Nt+1)
ca = np.zeros(Nt+1)
ca1 = np.zeros(Nt+1)
cb = np.zeros(Nt+1) 
ca[0] = ca0_0
ca1[0] = ca1_0
cb[0] = 0
for t in range(0, Nt):
    ca[t+1] = ca[t] - ca[t] * k1 * delt
    ca1[t+1] =  ca1[t] -ca1[t] *k2 *delt
    #here needs to come the cb part
```

which is absolutley wrong. I just can't grasp the idea what to do with the final B product.

Comment: why is it `cb[t+1] = ca1[t] - ...`?

Comment: That line is where im wrong, I don't know how to integrate ca1 and ca in to cb.

Comment: I think you need to control your time step.

Comment: No, why did you start with `ca1[t]` rather than `cb[t]` in the RHS?  What you should have is `cb[t] + db_dt * delt` where `db_dt` is whatever

Comment: I wanted to summarize cause both a1 and a are making the b component.

Comment: I get a negative result that way?

Comment: Nevermind solved it thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved with help of @user10354138

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
Nt = 1000
time = 10
delt = time/Nt
ca0_0 = 1
ca1_0 = 0.5
k1 = 1
k2 = 1
tt = np.linspace(0,time,Nt+1)
ca = np.zeros(Nt+1)
ca1 = np.zeros(Nt+1)
cb = np.zeros(Nt+1) 
ca[0] = ca0_0
ca1[0] = ca1_0
cb[0] = 0
for t in range(0, Nt):
    ca[t+1] = ca[t] - ca[t] * k1 * delt
    ca1[t+1] =  ca1[t] - ca1[t] *k2 *delt
    cb[t+1] =  cb[t] + (ca1[t+1]*k2 + ca[t+1]*k1)*delt
```